# Is there any way to increment a counter within a single line if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created this simple function:

```
def alpha_1(x):
    #num = 5
    counter = 65
    out = []
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x.isalpha():
            num = ord(x[i])
            out.append(chr(num+1 if 65 <= num <= 89 or 97 <= num <= 121 else counter))
        else:
            print("Not a character!")
            return 0
    return "".join(out)
```

Here I need to increment the counter when some values reaches the single line "if statement" as `count+=5`, so that I wont be getting the same 'A' for the values which don't fall under the specified range. I know it can be achieve using normal "if" statements.

I just want to know is there any way to achieve this within the single line statements?

Comment: Are you asking how to increment a variable within an if statement?

Comment: please specify your question but if you look for shorthand if -> `x = 10 if a > b else 11`

Comment: Just use a full *if statement*, don't use a conditional expression, it is purposefully limited in what you can do. You should keep conditional expressions readable and free of side-effects

Comment: yea, I will go with full "if", was just curious to know if it could be achieved in this way, Np..thanks all!!

Answer (score 1):

```
counter += 5 if statement else 0
```

you mean something like this?

this will add 5 to counter if statement is true , and add 0 to counter if statement is false

Comment: I tired this, but its throwing error as: `out.append(chr(num+1 counter += 5 if 65 <= num <= 89 or 97 <= num <= 121 else counter)) SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: what python version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Integers in python are immutable, which means that the only way to change the value that some variable like your `counter` points to is to re-assign it.

```
counter = 5 
counter = counter + 5  # tadaa!
```

There is no way around this, and assignments are [statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html), which means that you can't use them as the value for something (like an `if` statement).

You won't be able to do a one-line-if-statement-and-change-value until Python 3.8 comes around, when a dedicated [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) will become part of the language, which will allow exactly what you want:

```
if (counter := (counter + 5)) > something_else:
    # do something, also counter is now 5 bigger than before
```

---

But unless you want to [build the current cpython master](https://github.com/python/cpython#build-instructions) locally, you'll have to wait until [21.10.2019](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0569/#schedule) to start using it.